# Why changes by context.SaveChanges in EF not affect my mdf file?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, visual-studio, mdf

I have this model:

[image]

I use this code to add object to my database:

```
using (var c = new MyContext())
     {
          var con = new SunCondition()
          {
                TimeOffset = new TimeSpan(12, 2, 3),
                Name = "me",
                IsAfter = true,
                IsRise = true
          };
          c.ConditionSet.AddObject(con);
          c.SaveChanges();
     }
```

but it not adds any thing to database.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @Cris no error occurs!

Comment: can you show us the structure of your model object?

Comment: @Cris I cannot understand what you want? Q now have model img.

Comment: are you checking the correct database? I do not see any issues with your code. It *should* add or throw exception. Also, `Name` doesn't seem to be part of your entity. Have you migrated correctly? Do you need to run `Update-Database`?

Comment: @Default `Name` is part of parent entity(`Condition`). also I created my model from database, so I think it should be correct db.

Comment: check if a different/ unexpected local Db is being used. The context has Database.Connection attribute.   You can check the DB used. if the saveChanges return 1 for added 1 record, then there is a record in a db somewhere

Comment: The problem is you have no Primary Key on table SunCondition. Give it a try, set a primary key on the table.

Comment: @Zafar it now have primary key but since it is derived child, so I deleted its `Id` col. from entity. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj618293

Comment: You need that `Id` col back, otherwise EF does not know how to execute the INSERT on the child tables.

Comment: so what is new over here? have you tried setting a primary key? does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code have no problem.

I should say that always changes which program do on *mdf* file was on file that automatically copied to *bin/debug* or *bin/release* folder; so when I check my *mdf* file that is reachable in Visual Studio, it does not have any changes affected by application.